# Assign props and handlers to slot elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Let's say that I have a component called `tabs` which utilizes the default slot with another component, `tab`:

```
<tabs>
  <tab>a</tab>
  <tab>b</tab>
</tabs>
```

Is there any way to programmatically assign things like event handlers and props to the `tab` components, from within the `tabs` component?

The closest thing I can think of is something like:

```
<component v-for="item of $slots.default" :is="item.type.name" v-bind="item.props" @click="..." />
```

Is this how the api is intented to be used?

Comment: Personally I would use `provide/inject` for this instead

Comment: I think this video is very helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROGeJxI2L58

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thanks, pretty close. The downside is that he only picks out the tab titles and iterates on that, so anything else set in the slot is lost.